# Scroll to bottom of listview on page load in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a chat app. I want to display the last message at the end of the view list when the chat page is opened. Like WhatsApp and Telegram and...
I used the following code in the `initState` and I am getting the following error

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
   });
```

```
ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart':
Failed assertion: line 107 pos 12: '_positions.isNotEmpty'
```

I want the bottom of the listview to be displayed when the page loads and the user scrolls up to see previous messages

Comment: Give ```reverse: true``` in ListView. It'll build in reverse as you want.

Answer (score 1):

I know this issue has been solved may be. but if someone use getx ze may face this issue too. For this i am giving this solution:

```
 bool hasScrolled = false;
```

than

```
   Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      if (!hasScrolled) {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          controller.scrollController.animateTo(
            controller.scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            curve: Curves.easeOut,
          );
          hasScrolled = true;
        });
      }

    });
```

this solution is only for getx statemanagement